# How to redisplay the Back button after it was replaced by an Add button?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have a view with an Edit button on the right and a Back button on the left. When the user hits the Edit to enter the edit mode, I replace the back button with an Add button.

All works great up to this point.
I can't figure out how to display the Back button back again after the Edit button is hit to leave edit mode.

Comment: How are you adding the Add button?

Comment: // Add Add button
// Create a left Add button
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self 
action:@selector(handleAddButtonPressed:)];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];

[addButton release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you replace your back button with the add button, I suggest you save the old button so that you can replace it.

If you are using a navigation bar, it might be better to put your add button on the right; as a user will expect the back button to remain where it is.

Comment: Hi Paul,
I do use a navigation controller but I have an Edit button on the right.
As to your suggestion, the back button is configured in the parent view controller. How can I refer to it from the sub-view controller, where I manage the editing mode?